# Parsing data from Controller -> Controller -> View

Tags: laravel, session, session-variables, laravel-5.8

I have a form that will post data to ControllerONE store it in a database and redirects the user to `/list`. The route `/list` then uses the ControllerTwo to generate a view. However if I:

`return redirect('/list)->withSuccess('DONE!');`

I can't retrieve `$success` in the view, it's gone. Where is the issue?

*web.php*

`Route::get('/acp/nodes', 'NodeController@index');
Route::post('/acp/nodes/category/save', 'CategoriesController@save');`

*NodeController@index*

`return view('admin.nodes.edit')->with('categories', $categories);`

*CategoriesController@save*

`return redirect('acp/nodes')->withSuccess('true');`

With that I can't get either `$success` or `session('success')`.

Comment: Two options : `redirect()->back()->withSuccess([...])` or `return redirect()->route('acp/nodes)->withSuccess([...])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of fiddling around I noticed that I've got

`\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class`

in both `$middleware` & `$middleWareGroups`

Removing the duplicate entry fixed the issue entirely.

Answer (score 0):

you can't retrieve it cause it's not a variable passed to the view, it's a value stored on the flash array that you can retrieve using `session('success')`, and to test if it exists, you should use `session()->has('success')`.